# SSRS - Summarize first sheet, detail following sheets

Tags: reporting-services

I've got got a SSRS report containing multiple graphs and tables from different datasets. The data contains data for different branches. On the first page I need to display the totals of all the selected branches and on the following sheets, data per branch per sheet.

I've tried doing this using a rectangle, which works for objects that comes from the same dataset, but not from multiple datasets. Another problem with this approach is it page breaks into a new page before each instance of the object and also makes the objects that should still be on the first sheet, go onto the following sheets.

Also, I've got multiple parameters going into the report that comes from multiple datasets...

So I guess I need something like a rectangle, but one that accepts multiple datasets so that I can put all the objects on the page into it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to group the datasets into a single dataset with a query. But if this isn't possible I'd probably do the following:

Create a summary table for each of the branches. Put them next to each other so that they appear on the same worksheet when you export to Excel. Make sure you don't have "Page Break" selected in the "Properties" option in each of these tables.

You noted that you wanted a page for each Branch that includes specific detail. Again, you should create a table for each of the branches. However, this time, right click the table, click properties, and check mark "page break before". Do this for each Branch Detail table - so that each table will be on its only worksheet when you export to Excel.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Problem is that my data has different sources. What I ended up doing is creating a report that shows all the selected branched, and one that shows each branch per page. I then made a third report with the above two as sub-reports. Works perfectly.